# DropdownButton in flutter is giving error. How to fix?

Tags: flutter, debugging, flutter-widget

I have to use a `DropdownButton()` in my flutter app and I was getting some exceptions. Am I doing anything wrong and how do I go about fixing this?

```
...

class _CreateNewsArticleState extends State<CreateNewsArticle> {
  String dropdownvalue = 'Publish';
  var items = [
    'Publish at 22:00',
    'Publish in 9 hrs',
    'Publish in 5 hrs',
    'Publish in 3 hrs',
    'Publish in 1 hr',
    'Publish now'
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

...
```

This is the flutter `DropdownButton()` widget

```
DropdownButton(
                              value: dropdownvalue,
                              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                              items: items.map((String items) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                    value: items, child: Text(items));
                              }).toList(),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  dropdownvalue = "value";
                                });
                              },
                            )
```

error

```
Object? value
Type: Object?

A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.dartinvalid_assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `setState` you are not setting the var `value` but a String `"value"`.

```
 setState(() {
      dropdownvalue = value;
    });
```

Also, keep in mind that your `dropdownvalue` must be one of your values list or this will cause an Exception (`There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value`)

As mentioned by *Maikzen* declare your list as a `List<String>` and the DropdrownMenuItems as `DropdownMenuItem<String>`.

Comment: also don´t forget that the initial data of dropdownvalue has to be one of the items in the list, for example you can take the first element and initaly assign that one to the dropdownvalue

Answer (score 0):

Declare your list as List:

```
List<String> items = [
    'Publish at 22:00',
    'Publish in 9 hrs',
    'Publish in 5 hrs',
    'Publish in 3 hrs',
    'Publish in 1 hr',
    'Publish now'
  ];
```

Change your dropdownbutton like that:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
                              value: dropdownvalue,
                              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                              items: items.map((String items) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: items, child: Text(items));
                              }).toList(),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  dropdownvalue = "value";
                                });
                              },
                            )
```

You need to declare your type of data in your dropdown.